# How can I make my character 'flip' in Game Maker?

Tags: sprites, game-maker

I want my character to 'flip' or 'mirror' when I press 'A' or 'S'.
Thing is, I've placed the origin everywhere on the character and he seems to only face one direction.

Video showing what I see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zZEDpO0yAM&feature=youtu.be

(This video shows the character not 'mirroring' or 'flipping' properly.)

I have done hours of research into this, and I get the same results: "Make sure the sprite has the center origin."

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple if you think about it. All you have to do is scale the sprite using a negative factor, which in the end will cause sides to mirror around it's origin.

So all you have to do is assigning a negative scale using `image_xscale`:

```
image_xscale = -1;
```

The [documentation page for `image_xscale`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20properties/image_xscale.html) actually shows you an example with different scaling factors.

Comment: This only works correctly when the pivot is set at the center of the sprite(otherwise it's collision mask will be off the sprite).

Comment: @DH. I think a good designer will place the pivot at the center of a sprite most of the time, and when he doesn't he should know what to do to correct the following sprite behavior.